# Unable to load custom tile on google map using iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, overlay, gmsgroundoverlay

I'm trying to use custom tiles as overlay for google maps.
"https://tile.example.com/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
I used "GMSTileURLConstructor", but unable to load map on mobile app. I cannot seem to find anything online. Thanks in advance.

I used the following lines.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate{

    let urls: GMSTileURLConstructor = {z,x,y in
       let url = "https://tile.example.com/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
       print(url)
       return URL(string: url)
   }
```

Comment: where you tried this `iOS simulator` or `device`

Comment: ""https://tile.example.com/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" That's not a valid URL. `url` isn't nil, but `URL(string: url)` is. You need to percent escape "{" "}" I guess?  Or at least put the values, right not it's hard coded "z".

Comment: I tried in device.

Comment: Now I'm getting like this, but the app is not displaying the map. 
https://tile.example.com/hot/{3}/{6}/{3}.png                                                             
https://tile.example.com/hot/{3}/{7}/{2}.png
https://tile.example.com/hot/{3}/{7}/{3}.png
https://tile.example.com/hot/{3}/{6}/{4}.png
https://tile.example.com/hot/{3}/{6}/{5}.png
https://tile.example.com/hot/{3}/{7}/{4}.png

Comment: `URL(string: url)` is nil. Copy/paste that URL in Safari, you'll see. Also, as you can see, SO doesn't even consider the "{3}/{7}/{2}.png" as part of the URL. Don't you think that's a good lead to make it at least working in Safari?

Comment: Is this issue solved?